# Mercado pago Shipments

Tags: php, laravel, mercadopago

cordial saludo.

Actualmente estoy creando una pasarela de pagos con MercadoPago, he seguido la documentación y en desarrollo funciona perfectamente. El problema está en que el envío o Shipments, desde producción, envía un error **<Invalid argument supplied for foreach(), /vendor/mercadopago/dx-php/src/MercadoPago/Generic/RecuperableError.php">**. La clase que estoy usando es **Preference**. Veo que la clase **Shipments** se ha dejado sin uso, pero el objeto **Preference** especifica que lo usa. Aunque me parece ilógico que algo lo abandonen, pero otra clase la puede usar. Actualmente este es el código.

```
$payer = new Payer();
        $payer->name = $name;
        $payer->email = $customer['email'];
$shipments = new Shipments();
        $shipments->cost = $request->cart['operation'][0];
        $shipments->mode = 'not_specified';
$preference = new Preference();
        $preference->items = $items;
        $preference->payer = $payer;
        $preference->shipments = $shipments; // Aquí en desarrollo funciona bien, en producción sale error
$preference->save();
```

No veo en la documentación una solución a dicho problema. Pero veo en el apartado Monto del envío.

> > Si ya tienes estimado el envio desde tu sitio, puedes enviar el monto y mostrarlo por separado del total al ofrecer el pago.

> > Para configurarlo, agrega el nodo shipments con el valor del monto que quieras cobrar en el atributo cost y el valor not_specified en el atributo mode.

¿Y mi pregunta es en dónde agrego dicho nodo? Porque se pierde completamente en la documentación. ¿Debo agregarlo al objeto Shipments? ¿Hay que agregarlo en un atributo de la clase Preference aunque su clase no tiene un lugar para ello? o debo hacer algo distinto, puede ser que no entienda la documentación.

La versión que estoy usando es la 2.1

> > "mercadopago/dx-php": "^2.1",

La versión de php en desarrollo es la 7.2.19
La versión de php en producción es la 7.2.31

Agradezco vuestra ayuda porque no sé que pueda realizar. Si existe alguna forma mejor para realizar esto, agradezco dicha ayuda. Muchas gracias nuevamente!

Comment: Si envías el monto total, los items ya no son necesarios, funciona igual en viceversa, si envías los items, no debes poner el monto total por separado. Ya que cada item tiene su precio y cantidad y eso calcula el total.

Comment: Gracias. Qué pena contestar ahora, pero he tenido bastante trabajo. Tú solución es perfecta.